# Non-laravel package class not found

Tags: php, laravel-5, composer-php, lumen

I'm trying to use a non-laravel package added by composer to my project but no matter what I do, I get this message:

```
"Class 'Shaka\\Options\\Streams\\Stream' not found /home/server/Code/Project/app/Http/Controllers/General/FileController.php 61
```

I added the package to my **Lumen** project using composer like:

```
composer require aminyazdanpanah/php-shaka
```

Then I used it in my controller like:

```
use \Shaka\Options\Streams\Stream;

public function ShakaPlay()
{
    $stream1 = Stream::input(storage_path('app/media/3/123.mp4'));
    $stream1->streamSelector('video')->output('video.mp4');
}
```

But I get above error message, I checked the `Stream class` namespace it's :

```
namespace Shaka\Options\Streams;
```

Any suggestion?

Comment: Maybe the command `composer dump-autoload` will help load the classes.

Comment: use commands
composer dump-autoload
php artisan config:cache or delete it manually

Comment: @Mike I've done it but still the same.

Comment: @mohamedhassan As I mentioned i'm using lumen not laravel so there is no config file which cache anything